# How to design javaBean in Android

Tags: android, javabeans

I get json like :

```
{ 
  "success":[
   {"key":"headache", "value":false},
   {"key":"fatigue", "value":false}, 
   {"key":"sputum,color", "value": [
      "none",
      "green",
      "yellow",
      "white",
      "rustColor",
      "grayBlack"]
   }
  ],
 "errorCode":0}
```

I try to parser json , because I need to put key and value into RecyclerView.

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result.toString());
int errorCode = object.getInt("errorCode");
if (errorCode == 0){
    JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("success");
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
      JSONObject newObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
      String keyStr = newObject.getString("key");
      Object value = newObject.get("value");
      if (value instanceof String){
        String valueString = value.toString();
      else if (value instanceof Boolean)
        Boolean valueBoolean = (Boolean) value;
    }
}
```

Does any one can help me ?

Comment: Where is your parsing ?

Comment: I get json from api : result is json' result , so use JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result.toString()); see parser(result);

Comment: `SymptomData.newInstance(result.toString());` what is the body of this method ?

Comment: it's json to GSON fun : public static SymptomData newInstance(String jsonString)
Gson gson = new Gson();
SymptomData item;
item = gson.fromJson(jsonString, SymptomData.class);
In fact , my dataBean is wrong , see my json , key is boolean  , and also array

Comment: Please, edit your question with this code, for more clarity. But, yes, obvisouly, your JSON is not correct

Comment: @Broun , OK , I will edit my question

Comment: @林姿妤 I think the issue is with your JSON, on key "value" you have two types of data one is array another is boolean which is wrong, you have to fix it in your JSON that which key will have which type of data. you have to take different keys for two different type of values.

Comment: @ Shaifali Rajput : you are right , I find key  will two types , one is boolean , the other one is array , I wnat to fix it , but there are few refer about same key and defferent types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to fix your JSON issue, because it is not correct to have the same key for different value types.

If you can't, I think you do like this :

```
try {
    boolean boolValue = newObject.getBoolean("value");
    // here, you will have a Boolean
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // if an Exception is thrown, you have to deal with an array
    JSONArray array = newObject.getJSONArray("value");
    // here, you will have an Array
}
```

Comment: I find any way :
Object value = newObject.get("value");
if (value instanceof String){
  String valueString = value.toString();
}else if(value instanceof Boolean){
  Boolean valueBoolean = (Boolean) value;
}

I want to pass value to RecyclerView:
adapter  = new Adapter(this, value);

Comment: Regarding the adapter, you have to pass a list of objects as parameter. But it's not the purpose of your first question

Comment: :Yor are right , my question is how to parser json array of objects with Android which has different data types for same key.